# DRY in Nodejs Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, csrf

I have a bit of problem in following DRY in Node.js. How can I use csrf on different routes without copy pasting code in different places that needs csrf token?

app.js (main entry point)

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf({cookie: false});

//routes

var route1 = require('./app/routes/r1');
app.use('/', route1);

var route2 = require('./app/routes/r2');
app.use('/dashboard', r2);
```

i want to use csrfProtection on both routes but not sure how to do it without adding the code below in each file r1.js and r2.js

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf({cookie: false});

routes.get('/login', csrfProtection, function(req,res){
    res.render('login', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it. Need to refactor my code in `app.js`

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf({cookie: false});

var route1 = express.Router();
require('./app/routes/r1')(route1, csrfProtection);
app.use('/', route1);

var route2 = express.Router();
require('./app/routes/r2')(route2, csrfProtection);
app.use('/dashboard', route2);
```

then in my routes (r1.js)

```
module.exports = function(router, csrfProtection){
    router.get('/login', csrfProtection, function(req,res){
        res.render('login', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
    });
}
```

I can also use it in my other route.